# When is a complex measure non-zero on the space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Here's a silly question that I can't quite seem to figure out. I am a bit rusty on my measure theory.

When does a non-zero complex measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ with the Borel (or another) sigma algebra satisfy $\mu(X)\neq 0$?

Edit: I am trying to figure out a criterion on $\mu$ or the sigma algebra from which I get $$\mu \not\equiv 0 \implies \mu(X)\neq 0$$ in the case of a complex measure. For a real(positive) measure, this is trivial.

Thanks!

Comment: Always, if $\mu(X) = 0$, all sets have measure $0$ as subsets of $X$. So then we have the zero-measure.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am not sure why this is true - for a real measure you can use monotonicity, how do you do this for a complex measure?

Comment: The measure has an absolute value $|\mu|$ which is monotonous

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't \mu simply bounded above by it though? Do we get $|\mu|=0$ if $\mu = 0$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma As a simple example, consider $X=\{ a, b \}$ and $\mu$ defined by $\mu(\{a \})=1$, $\mu( \{b \}) =-1$, $\mu(X)=0$. This is a non-zero signed measure. In this case $|\mu|(X)=2$.

Comment: What kind of criteria are you looking for? This question is rather vague. You could decompose $\mu$ into signed measures $\mu_r+i\mu_i$ or positive measures $\mu=\mu_{r,+}-\mu_{r,-}+i\mu_{i,+}-i\mu_{i,-}$ and give criteria on these.

Comment: @Dunham For real (positive) measures for example, the whole space always has a non-zero measure, if the measure is non-zero. However, for signed and complex measures, I am unsure if it is possible for $\mu(X)$ to be $0$ and for $\mu$ to not be identically $0$ on the sigma algebra, i.e. Is it possible that $\mu_+ = \mu_-$? Or  in the complex case, is it possible that $\mu_r(X)=0$, $\mu_i(X)=0$ but there exists $E\subset X$ such that $\mu(E)\neq 0$. I have a Radon measure in particular.

Comment: @DominiqueR.F. Thanks! For some reason, I didn't even consider discrete measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For signed as well as complex measures, you can always find examples where $\mu(X)=0$, but $\mu$ is nonzero. On $\mathbb{R}$, let $\mu(E)=\int_E f dm$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure and $\int_{(-\infty,\infty)} f dm=0$.